# Add form info into SQLite database python

Tags: python, html, sqlite

I am a beginner at databases and I want to make a form in my website that requires any user's information. So the user needs to write in their name and email, add a description to an image and upload the image itself. I want to store the information into an SQLite table in Python.

This is my form:

```html
    <form role="form" method="post" id="reused_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">
                Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                   id="name" name="name" required maxlength="50">

        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">
                Email:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control"
                   id="email" name="email" required maxlength="50">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">
                Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" name="message"
                      id="message" placeholder="Your Message Here"
                      maxlength="6000" rows="7"></textarea>
        </div>
        <br>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">
                Image Upload:</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image" required>
        </div>
        
        <input type="submit" name="my_button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I've started with this python code:

```py
connection = sqlite3.connect('database1.sqlite')
cur = connection.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Artpieces')
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE Artpieces ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL, email TEXT NOT NULL, description TEXT NOT NULL, photo BLOB NOT NULL)')
```

I don't know how to continue. The image part is pretty difficult and I found a tutorial, but I doesn't say how to store an image from a user (so not me). Here it is: https://pynative.com/python-sqlite-blob-insert-and-retrieve-digital-data/ .

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How were you planning to submit the form? You will in general need an `<input type="submit">` element in your form. Check for example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: ah yes, sorry for that, I added it now.

Comment: I believe that for your purpose you 'd better use a web-application framework like `Flask`. Despite saying _web-application framework_, don't get intimidated! You can also build an application that will run at your local computer...
An example of such an application, with Flask and SQLite can be found [here](https://www.tutorialandexample.com/flask-sqlite/)

Comment: instead of deleting/creating  your tables everytime you can just `connection = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')`

Comment: @diggusbickus he can do it yes in case he chooses to abandon the web interface and work with SQLite only through the script

Comment: @Yannis P. Yes, I'll look into that. Thanks!